# How to send long data Using NamedPipes c#?

Tags: c#, pipe

Im Trying to send an image to another pc  using namedpipes 
we are using this code:

`byte[] DataToBeSend;`

```
    NamedPipeClientStream PipeClient =
    new NamedPipeClientStream(_Nombre, _Pipe,
    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, PipeOptions.None,                      TokenImpersonationLevel.None,
    HandleInheritability.None);
    DataToBeSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(_Dato.Length);
    int HL = _Dato.Length;
    int Longitud = BitConverter.ToInt32(_Dato, 0);
    PipeClient.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("Conected");
    PipeClient.Write(DataToBeSend, 0, DataToBeSend.Length);
    PipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
    PipeClient.Write(_Dato, 0,HL);
    PipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
    PipeClient.Close();
```

Firts I send the length of the buffer and then  the buffer ( who contains the image on bytes)  the problem is that  that image is 100 MB  and a named pipe cant send such as big infomation , what is the best form to solve this problem? there is a metod able to convert  this buffer in a smaller one!

Comment: when posting code please show all relevant code for example if this code is within a method please show the method signature and wrap your code in the method body appropriately also try looking at this msdn example if it's not what you're looking for then try a google search or see if `WMI` can handle this task https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement your own flow control. You will need to break your payload into more manageable chunks (~1KB maybe) and send each chunk (packet) at a time.

In order to effectively do this, you will need a header for the payload to know how to reassemble on the other side. You will probably need at least an ID, Index, and IsLast fields.

```
ID = A unique identifier indicating all packets that belong together
Index = The index of the packet in the group (same ID)
IsLast = Indicating this is the last packet of the group and you can now process as a whole
```